# ElasticSearch phrase_match incorrectly matches query

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-5

I am full text searching on my ES5 endpoint, I am trying to see if one of these phrases might appear in the full-text. I have a test example indexed which should not appear from this query. Unfortunately, it is appearing. Through trial and error, the "public right of way" phrase_match matches to the phrase "public wrong of way", even though the phrase_slop is 0. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Query:

```
{
"query": { 
    "bool" : {
        "should": [
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "passenger vessel",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "outdoor developed area",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "public right of way",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "emergency transportable housing",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "medical diagnostic equipment",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "classroom acoustic",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "shared use paths",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "self-service transaction machine",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase" :  {
                    "note_1": {
                        "query": "transportation vehicles",
                        "slop": 0
                    } 
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-explain.html) parameter with your query to see why it matches your test example? Also, is this the full query or "just" an extract of it? Behavior of the should clause will [vary depending if there are must or filter clauses](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: You can use named queries to see which one of those phrases is matched as this is one big should query